# Invalid signature from repo.skype.com: how can I clear this?

Tags: apt, package-management, skype, signature

Today I did `sudo apt upgrade` and then, as a double-check, did `sudo apt update`.  The latter terminated with:

```
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                       
Get:6 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease [4,502 B]                                        
Err:6 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client Repository <se-um@microsoft.com>
Fetched 4,502 B in 5s (894 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client Repository <se-um@microsoft.com>
W: Failed to fetch https://repo.skype.com/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client Repository <se-um@microsoft.com>
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

In an attempt to clear this problem, I called `sudo apt remove skypeforlinux` and then did another `sudo apt update`.  The update again terminated with the message about the invalid signature.

How can I clear up this invalid signature problem?

```
$ uname -mrs
Linux 5.4.0-77-generic x86_64
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
```

Comment: I really wish someone from Microsoft would step up and fix this bug or a volunteer who supports the ubuntu package distribution tooling  ... this issue is ongoing and impacting everyone using skype

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The validity of the signature key has expired, and only after a few days Microsoft generated a new key. The key replacement in your system is not automatic and you need to delete the old key and add the new one.

There are two ways two solve the issue: one, using the traditional `apt-key add` command, the other one adding manually the new key to the keyring.

**# Solution valid until Ubuntu 21.04 (including it)**

You can delete the no longer valid key:

```
sudo apt-key del 1F3045A5DF7587C3
```

and then re-add the new valid key:

```
curl https://repo.skype.com/data/SKYPE-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add -
```

Running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` you should see no errors.

**# Solution valid in Ubuntu 21.04 and future releases**

When you try to add an APT repository key using `apt-key` in Ubuntu, you may see the following message:

> Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).

The apt-key man page mentions that:

> use of apt-key is deprecated, except for the use of apt-key del in maintainer scripts to remove existing keys from the main keyring.

So, if you use a version of Ubuntu until 21.04, you are ok using `apt-key del` and `apt-key add`, but for the following versions you must manually add the key in the keyring (in Ubuntu 21.04 both solutions work perfectly: I tested both of them).

You can delete the no longer valid key:

```
sudo apt-key del 1F3045A5DF7587C3
```

Download the key and add it to the keyring:

```
curl https://repo.skype.com/data/SKYPE-GPG-KEY | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/skype-stable-archive-keyring.gpg
```

Open the `skype-stable.list` file...

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
```

...and modify the first line in this way:

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/skype-stable-archive-keyring.gpg] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main
```

Running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` you should see no errors.

Comment: I was on the unstable channel and the instructions worked except that I needed to quote "unstable main" in the list files. I had one for stable and one for unstable, both of them referred to the unstable.